# extracting IP info from website with IP changing each search

Tags: json, ip, kql

Im trying to extract IP info from IPinfo website but be able to have the query have the IP set prior to the extract data function so its easy to change the searched IP and possibly use it for searching the IP when using Signinlogs etc... see below roughly what iv got atm.

```
let _IP = "'[INSERT IP HERE]'"; //IP im searching for
let _link = strcat('@"https://ipinfo.io/', _IP, '/json"'); //attempt to concat the IP into the URL
let IPCheck = externaldata(ip: string, city: string, region : string, country : string, org : string )[_link] //external data function to pull json data from URL
with(format=multijson);
IPCheck
```

The below works. as I want it to

let IPCheck = externaldata(ip: string, city: string, region : string, country : string, org : string )[@"https://ipinfo.io/[INSERT IP HERE]/json"] //external data function to pull json data from URL
with(format=multijson);
IPCheck

But want to create the URL before hand, creating this as a string does NOT appear to work

Any ideas on how to work around this or a better way of extracting this data?

Comment: "does NOT appear to work" is not a useful description for whomever is reading this post. If you get an error, share its details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [http_request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/http-request-plugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer) plugin.
Having said that, I have no idea why you would like to do such a thing within ADX.

```
let IP = "8.8.8.8";
let URL = strcat("https://ipinfo.io/", IP, "/json");
evaluate http_request(URL)
```

| ResponseHeaders | ResponseBody | ResponseStatusCode | ResponseReasonPhrase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"access-control-allow-origin":"*","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","referrer-policy":"strict-origin-when-cross-origin","x-envoy-upstream-service-time":"1","strict-transport-security":"max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains","vary":"Accept-Encoding","Alt-Svc":"h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Date":"Fri, 30 Dec 2022 11:16:14 GMT","Via":"1.1 google"} | {"ip":"8.8.8.8","hostname":"dns.google","anycast":true,"city":"Mountain View","region":"California","country":"US","loc":"37.4056,-122.0775","org":"AS15169 Google LLC","postal":"94043","timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","readme":"https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"} | 200 | OK |

Comment: Aww this seemed a lot niced and easier buty http_request is disabled in my enviroment :(